# Custom SpinBoxField example

Tags: blackberry

I'm attempting to build a custom SpinBoxField on the Blackberry that displays an icon next to text. I've been unable to find any example code. Subclassing SpinBoxField and implementing drawRow, get, and getCount() have got me part of the way there, but my implementation still doesn't look or work like the TextSpinBoxField in the RIM Blackberry library.

Has anyone source code for such a field that they would be willing to share here?